# Webm video flashes compression artefacts

Tags: virtualbox, video, compression

Doing som testing on capturing video from VirtualBox for a screencasting project. VirtualBox uses webm for video and it works sort of OK. However, it has "flashes" of heavy compression artefacts.

http://youtu.be/B1WaSFRQsHY

In the video you can see it at 0:14 and 0:25. It's not much, but it's kind of jarring. Anyone know why this is, and if it can be mitigated? Can I get VirtualBox to record something else than webm? (Better suited for editing after recording)

(The raw webm-video acts exactly as the YouTube video, so it's not YouTube's fault.)